# "Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed." because of csproj misconfiguration

Tags: c#, .net-core, gitlab-ci-runner

This happens randomly when trying to compile a fairly large solution with only a few dozen csprojs referencing the particular dll that fails to copy.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="SomeLabrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\lib\some-library.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

My question is, How do I tell the dotnet compiler to not copy this library, or do it once, or compare it before copying or don't lock the file in a Linux system? Ah, sanity, I miss thee.

Comment: please could you provide the message error ?

Comment: @sayahimad That is the error message in the title. Complete error message reads: `error MSB3027: Could not copy "/home/gitlab-runner/builds/***/*/.../lib/some-library.dll" to "../../../bin/publish/some-library.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.  [/home/gitlab-runner/builds/***/*/..../*.csproj]`

Comment: did you try to delete bin and obj folder , don't forget to restart vs?

Comment: This is happening when running a ci build job on Linux. there is no windows or vs involved.

Comment: it's supposed to be the same whether its on vs or ci-build

Comment: The ci build processes cease to exist after each run. the build interferes with itself not another run.

Comment: What if you remove the HintPath tag and make the Reference tag self-closing?

Comment: @Mitulátbáti I can't. Even if it works. it breaks the IDE. a few million errors.:)

Comment: @Behrooz how sure are you that `../../../bin/publish/some-library.dll` is not in used at the time you try to replace it? Maybe a process not exiting clean?

The compiler steps are battle tested by multi-million devs... - there should not be such a huge flaw.

Comment: Have you tried running Strace to see what is going on in the weeds with the copy operation?  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Strace

Comment: @Dominik because It only started when i moved my projects to a /src directory and my build times increased three fold. Server reboots should do.

Comment: @DanCsharpster I'm familiar with strace. I don't know why I didn't try it. I think the .net compiler is a managed library though. Either way, I will try it. Thank You.

Comment: @DanCsharpsterThanks for all the suggestions. Since not much time is left on the bounty I'll try everything mentioned here tonight and report back. if any of them turn out to be the solution, I'll ask you to make it into an answer so I can give the reward.

Comment: @Dominik  previous comment.

Comment: I wish you good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't comment yet, so I try an answer.

I was facing this issue in a big project as well, a couple of years ago. I tracked it down to a specific process VisualStudio is starting during compile time, which was blocking the .dll. That process however didn't seem to be required. Therefore I added a taskkill command to the post build to kill it. I don't remember what the blocking process was.

You can however do the same as me back then, and get [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), which can help you find handles.

When Process Explorer is started you can hit CTRL+F to search for a handle, you basically enter only your .dll name there. If any process has a file handle to your dll it will show up in your search. You have a pretty good chance to find that process while you're getting the "could not copy" error, it's being retried for a couple of seconds.

If you find that process you can also try a search in that context. Maybe there's a better solution than using taskkill nowadays.

Comment: Unfortunately(who am I kidding. fortunately) this is happening in a Linux environment and the environment is fresh before each compilation.

Comment: It might still be worth a try to investigate it. And on linux your tools are way more powerful, a quick research showed that you probably can use [lslocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85994/how-to-list-processes-locking-file) to find the filehandle

Answer (score 1):

Found the curlprit. It wasn't because of the csproj or sln files, or even the library file. It was the dotnet target configuration `publish` that was misbehaving. It was added around the time that I ihad restructured my solution and added `/bin`, `/lib`, `/src`, etc to the root directory. because it's always a good idea to change multiple things at the same time.
Removing `-publish` from the compiler flags fixed the issue.
Turns out battle testing by a million devs that don't have hundreds of projects in solutions doesn't bring out some bugs:)